# Coloured half lines in a matrix

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix

I was wondering how I could create this matrix in LaTeX:

[image]

I know how to do the matrix part but my question is the lines, how can I make them stop in (1,1), (2,2) and (3,3)?

Comment: I'd give `nicematrix` a try, since it is build using tikz this should not be a problem.

Comment: It would help people if you could edit into your question some code that produces the parts you know how to do, it is fine if you don't know how to add the colour lines (that's what this site is for) but it helps people help you when there is a starting point beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possibility with `nicematrix` and `tikz`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 2pt}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-col]
\color{red}\Delta_1 & \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1^2} & \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1^2} & \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1^2}\\
\color{green}\Delta_2 & \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1^2} & \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1^2} & \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1^2}\\
\color{blue}\Delta_3 & \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1^2} & \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1^2} & \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1^2}
\CodeAfter
\tikz{
    \draw[red, shorten >=-3mm] (1-|2) -- (2-|2) -- (2-|1);
    \draw[green, shorten >=-3mm] (1-|3) -- (3-|3) -- (3-|1);
    \draw[blue, shorten >=-3mm] (1-|4) -- (4-|4) -- (4-|1);
}
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is wonderful !!!

Comment: And how did it make it look squared, before my matrix was more of a rectangle, i think it is related to NIceMatrix i will have a look

Comment: `\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 2pt}` adjusts vertical space between rows.